# Element cannot be resolved to a type 

Tags: java, jsoup

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class jsoup {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
                    + "<body><p id='xxx'>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
        Document doc = (Document)Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element el = doc.getElementById("xxx"); 
    }
}
```

When I run code above, I receive a

> error:Element cannot be resolved to a type in line "Element el = doc.getElementById("xxx");"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

That's just a compilation error. You need to import [`Element`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html).

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
```

Read the [Jsoup javadocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) for all packages and classes. They are linked in [Jsoup home page](http://jsoup.org). Please also note that Jsoup doesn't use `Document` from `org.w3c.dom`. Remove that line and the unnecessary cast.